# Deploy Alexa skill on amazon using circle ci

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, circleci, ask-cli

I have created a Alexa skill and deployed from local system to the amazon. It is working fine.
Now I am trying to use circle ci to setup the alexa skill.
I have used ask cli to deploy the skill, It is throwing error.

```
- run:
         name: 'npm install serverless'
         command: |
         sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g ask-cli
- run:
          name: 'serverless deploy'
          command: |
             serverless deploy --region us-west-2 --stage dev
      - run:
          name: 'echo $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID'
          command: echo $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
      - run:
          name: 'echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
          command: echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - run:
          name: 'echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
          command: echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - run:
          name: 'echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'
          command: echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - run:
          name: 'echo $ASK_CLI_CONFIG'
          command: echo $ASK_CLI_CONFIG
      - run:
          name: Setup Environment Variables
          command: |
            echo 'LOCAL="en-US"' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run:
          name: 'skill deploy'
          command: |
            mkdir -p ~/.ask
            echo 'ASK_CLI_CONFIG:$ASK_CLI_CONFIG' > ~/.ask/cli_config
            ask deploy --target skill --debug
```

I am getting error 
Invalid json: /home/circleci/.ask/cli_config
Exited with code 1

Help will be most appreciated.

Please let me know how to fix it.

when i try only sudo npm install -g ask-cli 
it is not installing the ask cli, it is throwing error also.

Comment: You could maybe add `ask-cli` as a dev dependency, then do an `npm install` for your dependencies. Add an NPM script to deploy.

Comment: I tried adding in the dev dependency..it is showing ask command not found.

Comment: What do you have in your NPM script for running it?

Comment: {
  "name": "skillalexa",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-alexa-skills": "^0.1.0",
    "ask-cli":"1.7.7"
  }
}

Comment: I meant in the scripts section, so something like... `"scripts": { "deploy": "ask deploy --target skill --debug" }`

Which you'd run by `npm run deploy`.

Comment: I added the NPM script.. it is throwing error as ask command not found

Comment: can you please help me with any github link which is using circle ci to deploy alexa skill

Comment: I'm not aware of any, sorry. I use Serverless to deploy my lambdas. I only use the ASK CLI to deploy my skill manually - I don't want the skill updated all of the time, only the code.